# elasticsearch canvas, is there a text input box to query index?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, canvas

I am building a canvas dashboard (Elastic 7.6) and have been using the different elements like the dropdown list, however I would prefer for the end user to enter in a value to query my index, eg company name

The company name field is a keyword in my mapping.

Is there an element I can use to achieve this?